# MySqli is returning NULL for values and cannot insert or select

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My problem is that my db have no errors and still ignore my inserts, selects etc.
So i tried var_dump() and it gives NULL for all variables. That is my connection query:

```
 $this->conexao = new mysqli('localhost:3307','root','', 'construsite');
```

And this is wrong, i think:

```
 public 'conexao' => 
 object(mysqli)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'client_info' => null
  public 'client_version' => null
  public 'connect_errno' => null
  public 'connect_error' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'host_info' => null
  public 'info' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'server_info' => null
  public 'server_version' => null
  public 'stat' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'protocol_version' => null
  public 'thread_id' => null
  public 'warning_count' => null
```

and my function to insert that is ignored:

```
public function registro(){
    //comando sql para inserir novo cliente
    $comando = "INSERT INTO clientes(id, nome_cliente, email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, data_nasc_cliente) "
    . "VALUES (NULL, '$this->nome_cliente', '$this->email_cliente', '$this->telefone_cliente', '$this->senha_cliente', STR_TO_DATE( '$this->data_nasc_cliente', '%Y/%d/%m')";
    //executa o comando
    $registro_resultado = $this->conexao->query($comando); //executa o comando
    return $registro_resultado;
}
```

I tried to find in google and here but i could not. (Sorry my bad english!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is primary key, and primary key doesn't accept null. if your primary key auto increment so remove id from insert query.

```
$comando = "INSERT INTO clientes(nome_cliente, email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, data_nasc_cliente) "
    . "VALUES ('$this->nome_cliente', '$this->email_cliente', '$this->telefone_cliente', '$this->senha_cliente', STR_TO_DATE( '$this->data_nasc_cliente', '%Y/%d/%m'))";
```

Comment: Didn't worked, I replaced NULL for '' and still not working

Comment: your primary key must have a value.

Comment: it's auto incremented

Comment: Still not working, you prefer me to print the var dump and the db?

Comment: and why this STR_TO_DATE( '$this->data_nasc_cliente', '%Y/%d/%m')

Comment: The problem is that have no error, It just don't seem to be connected.

Comment: That's a try to insert date in correct format but that's not the problem, i think

Comment: INSERT INTO clientes(nome_cliente, email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, data_nasc_cliente) VALUES ('Diego Kfuri', 'kkfuri@gmail.com', '5531991817228', '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70', STR_TO_DATE( '24/01/1998', '%Y/%d/%m')

Comment: you should close the ) at the end of query

Comment: Yes, I corrected this but seems to have not worked yet

Comment: can send your table structure, create query?

Comment: STR_TO_DATE( '24/01/1998', '%d/%m/%Y') your format must match with your date

Comment: Tyvm!!!!!!! It worked, sorry for my bad english and my errors, I'm still learning, but really thank you!!